# bash: syntax error with pandas.read_excel

Tags: bash, ipython

I am trying to input this command:

```
example = pd.read_excel('080615_gene_expression.xlsx' , index_col = 0)
```

but I get this error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I have tried changing quotes, spaces etc = no change

The command works in IPython 3.0.0.

Comment: Are you sure you are typing the command inside a python / ipython shell? it sounds like you are typing it into a bash shell instead.

Comment: I solved it. AND YES you were correct! Rookie starting out here. Thanks!

Comment: As you're a new user: if you found an answer to your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" to the left of it to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid"!

Answer (score 1):

If I start your command in a bash, I get an interesting

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Start a Python interpreter by typing `python`<kbd>Enter</kbd> and then try the command again **;)**

---

In my case, I get a

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '080615_gene_expression.xlsx'
```

but in my case that's absolutely normal as *I don't have your excel sheet*.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Python command, not a Bash command. You can run a Python shell and then run your code by hand by typing:

```
ipython
```

If you get an error that `ipython` command was not found, install it via:

```
pip install ipython
```

If you're putting this into a script and trying to run it from the shell, your Python script needs to start with (first line of the file):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Then you can run it from Bash as:

```
chmod +x my_script
./my_script.py
```